# How can I partition by date without it making 3 partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, parquet

I'm trying to migrate some unsorted datasets that're currently setup in Hive like so;

```
database.table_name_20230523
database.table_name_20230524
database.table_name_20230525
```

To a single table that is partitioned by date, eg;
database.table_name.

The code I've got looks like the following.

`spark.read.parquet('/path/to/data/20230524/*') df.sort('column1','column2').write.partitionBy('date').saveAsTable('database.table_name')` 
This works OK, however the data in the 20230524 folder contains small amounts of data from 20230523 and 20230525, which ends up creating tiny <100K files in those dirs.

Is there a way I can do this? I'll likely be working with daily datasets well over a 2T so while I could tune a single node to handle the 400G, it is unlikely I could do it for the 2T datasets.
I feel like I'm probably doing something wrong, but can't find a relevant example or doc that will do what I'm after.
If it matters, the source data is parquet ~450G/day and split into ~2000 files.
I'm running Spark 3.2.1, Hadoop 3.3.1 and submitting the Spark jobs via YARN.

I thought I could use sortWithinPartition to fix this, so that data is partitioned into the dates before being sorted which would not generate the small files.

```
df.repartition('date').sortWithinPartitions('column1','column2').write.partitionBy('date').saveAsTable('database.table_name')
```

This however ends up failing as it sends 3 tasks to nodes. 2 of which finish quickly, likely the ones handling the 0523/0525 the task handling the 0524 date just stalls (as it'll have >400G of data).